# Undefined constant namespaces

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm learning about the namespaces in PHP. Here is the code I use

lib1.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Lib1;

const MYCONST = "App\Lib1\MYCONST";

function MyFunction() {
    return __FUNCTION__;
}

class MyClass {
    static function WhoAmI() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

app.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
require_once 'lib1.php';

echo App\Lib1\MYCONST;
```

The problem is that for some reason I get

```
Undefined constant 'App\Lib1\MYCONST' in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/namespaces/myapp.php
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Lib1;

const MYCONST = "App\Lib1\MYCONST";

function MyFunction() {
    return __FUNCTION__;
}

class MyClass {
    static function WhoAmI() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}


header('Content-type: text/plain');
require_once 'lib1.php';
use App\Lib1;
echo \App\Lib1\MYCONST;
```

Try this though tbh I'm not massively familiar with namespacing in php.  I'm not sure the use is 100% required or if indeed it needs the leading \ on it it could need to be use \App\Lib1

I would also think that instead it should just be namespace App; in your declaration file then you'd do echo \App\MYCONST;  but again not familiar enough it could be fine with sub namespace